# How Can I Use cordova plugins on Ionic 3?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm new on the "Ionic World" and I'm trying to use this plugin on my Ionic app: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-imei

However, when I try to use the plugin on my controller, it doesn't recognize the plugin. Here's the piece of code:

```
  obterIMEI(){
var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;
var imei = cordova.plugins.imei;
permissions.requestPermission(permissions.READ_PHONE_STATE, success, error);
function error() {
  this.msgOptions.message = 'Não há permissões para acessar o IMEI!';
  this.msg.create(this.msgOptions).present();      
}
function success(status) {
    imei.get(
        function (imei) {
          console.log('worked');
          this.imei = imei;
        },
        function () {
          console.log('error');
          this.msgOptions.message = 'Erro ao acessar o IMEI!';
          this.msg.create(this.msgOptions).present();                            
        }
    );
}
```

}

The lines **cordova.plugins.permissions** and **window.plugins.imei.get** are not recognized and when I try to run the app, I get the following error:

```
[10:20:54]  typescript: src/pages/imei/imei.ts, line: 27
        Cannot find name 'cordova'.

  L26:  obterIMEI(){
  L27:    var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;
  L28:    permissions.requestPermission(permissions.READ_PHONE_STATE, success, error);

[10:20:54]  typescript: src/pages/imei/imei.ts, line: 35
        Property 'plugins' does not exist on type 'Window'.

  L34:  function success(status) {
  L35:      window.plugins.imei.get(
  L36:          function (imei) {
```

I already installed the plugin using the terminal but it doesn't work. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a Ambient variable and use it. Example :

```
// Global ambient variable
declare var cordova: any;

function buscarImei() {
    var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;
    var imei = cordova.plugins.imei;
    permissions.requestPermission(permissions.READ_PHONE_STATE, success, error);
    function error() {
        alertify.error("Sem Permissão para a busca  de IMEI!");
    }
    function success(status) {
        imei.get(
            function (imei) {
                // NOTE : This is Ionic 1 syntax. You need to check for accessing in Ionic 2/3 ( Scope variable depreciated from ionic 2 onwards ) 
                $scope.config.imei = imei;
            },
            function () {
                alertify.error("Erro ao carregar IMEI!!");
            }
        );
    }
};
```

Comment: I added the variable and changed my function as you did and I got this error: `ReferenceError: cordova is not defined` . I'm gonna update my code on the question.

Comment: Yes you will get "cordova is not defined error " as you would have loaded the ionic app onto a browser for which the plugins you use will NOT have support. Build the Apk and try running the app onto a mobile. It should work fine as expected.